# LINQ converts "0" to NULL in insert

Tags: c#, sql, linq

When inserting a database row with LINQ, a `0` (as an `int`) gets converted to `NULL` and does not show up in the insert statement:

```
DatabaseCAMAE db = new DatabaseCAMAE(Database.Instance.Connection);
db.Log = Console.Out;
camaeprotocol cpr = new camaeprotocol
{
    sid = 0,
    prrevision = 0,
    ataction = "Scan created",
    prdescription = "Scan created",
    prtimestamp = DateTime.Now,
    uid = 0
};
db.camaeprotocol.InsertOnSubmit(cpr);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Where `sid` and `prrevision` are the primary key.
The log outputs:

```
INSERT INTO "main"."camae_protocol"  
   ("at_action", "pr_description", "pr_timestamp", "u_id") 
VALUES (:ataction, :prdescription, :prtimestamp, :uid)
-- :ataction: Input String (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Scan created]
-- :prdescription: Input String (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Scan created]
-- :prtimestamp: Input DateTime (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [16.04.2013 07:52:44]
-- :uid: Input Int32 (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [0]
-- Context: SQLite Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 0.20.0.0
```

And an exception is thrown (constraint violation), because LINQ does not attempt to insert the `0` `sid` and `0` `prrevision`. What to do to fix this?

Comment: What are their data types?

Comment: They are both real "int", not "int?".

Comment: No, they are not set to "auto increment"

Comment: I think this exception is because of duplication in the database. And you're getting constraint violation cuz of that. Let me know if thats the case so that I can write it as answer.

Comment: No, sadly I can eliminate that error. The error is thrown even when the table is completely empty.

Comment: The exception message is: "constraint failed - camae_protocol.s_id may not be NULL"

Comment: Try with a non-zero value and see if you still get the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the log it seems that the "sid" and "prrevision" fields are not included in the INSERT statement. If you marked these fields in your entity as composite primary keys ([Key] as annotation or HasKey() in fluent), EF will not send these to your database and will assume that they are autogenerated.

You can tell EF not to consider them autogenerated by setting

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerationOption.None)]
```

on the two key fields.